# Adding two linked lists and outputting the result in a new linked list discussion in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, addition

Question:

You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Example:

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

Suggested Solution:

```
function ListNode(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
}

// adding two Linked Lists.
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
 const temp = new ListNode(0);
 let resultPointer = temp;
 var digit = 0;
 var carryover = 0;
 while(
   l1!== null ||
   l2 !== null
  ){
    var sum = 0;
    if(l1!== null){
      sum += l1.val;
      l1 = l1.next;           
    }

    if(l2!== null){
      sum += l2.val;
      l2 = l2.next;
    }

    sum = sum + carryover;
    carryover = sum >= 10 ? 1 : 0;
    resultPointer.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
    resultPointer = resultPointer.next;
 }
  return temp.next;    
};
```

Output: [7,0,8];

Why does the following change outputs an [] list.

```
       let resultPointer = new ListNode(0);
       return resultPointer.next();
```

Any Suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare

```
let resultPointer = new ListNode(0);
```

It creates a new linked list. It doesn't have any connection whatsoever with `temp`. Then after the execution of while loop, your `resultPointer` points to the last entry of that list and it doesn't have any linked list further to that pointer. So when you return `resultPointer.next()` - it's actually an empty list.

On the contrary - in your suggested solution, `temp` is actually the head of the linked list. For iteration - it uses the `resultPointer`.
So even after executing the while loop, `temp` is still the head of the linked list. So returning `temp.next()` is actually returning the list further to that head of the linked list.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I come up with this code for this program using Queues, Hope this helps someone

```
// C# program to add two numbers represented by Linked
// Lists using Queues
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class List
{

    public class Node
    {

        public int data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public static Node head1, head2;
    // function that calculates and prints the sum of two
    // numbers represented by linked lists
    public void addTwoLists(Node l1, Node l2)
    {
        Node prev = null;
        // Create 3 Queues
        Queue<Node> q1 = new Queue<Node>();
        Queue<Node> q2 = new Queue<Node>();
        Queue<Node> q3 = new Queue<Node>();
        // Fill first Queue with first List Elements
        while (l1 != null)
        {
            q1.Enqueue(l1);
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        // Fill second Queue with second List Elements
        while (l2 != null)
        {
            q2.Enqueue(l2);
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        int carry = 0;
        // Fill the third Queue with the sum of first and second Queues
        while (q1.Count != 0 && q2.Count != 0)
        {
            int sum
                = q1.Peek().data + q2.Peek().data + carry;
            Node temp = new Node(sum % 10);
            q3.Enqueue(temp);
            if (sum > 9)
            {
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
            }
            q1.Dequeue();
            q2.Dequeue();
        }
        while (q1.Count != 0)
        {
            int sum = carry + q1.Peek().data;
            Node temp = new Node(sum % 10);
            q3.Enqueue(temp);
            if (sum > 9)
            {
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
            }
            q1.Dequeue();
        }
        while (q2.Count != 0)
        {
            int sum = carry + q2.Peek().data;
            Node temp = new Node(sum % 10);
            q3.Enqueue(temp);
            if (sum > 9)
            {
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
            }
            q2.Dequeue();
        }
        // If carry is still present create a new node with
        // value 1 and Enqueue it to the third Queue
        if (carry == 1)
        {
            Node temp = new Node(1);
            q3.Enqueue(temp);
        }
        // Link all the elements inside third Queue with
        // each other
        if (q3.Count != 0)
            prev = q3.Peek();
        while (q3.Count != 0)
        {
            Node temp = q3.Peek();
            q3.Dequeue();
            if (q3.Count == 0)
            {
                temp.next = null;
            }
            else
            {
                temp.next = q3.Peek();
            }
        }
        printList(prev);
    }

    /* Utility function to print a linked list */
    public void printList(Node head)
    {
        while (head.next != null)
        {
            Console.Write(head.data + " -> ");
            head = head.next;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(head.data);
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        List list = new List();

        // creating first list
        Node head1 = new Node(2);
        head1.next = new Node(4);
        head1.next.next = new Node(3);
        Console.Write("First List : ");
        list.printList(head1);

        // creating second list
        Node head2 = new Node(5);
        head2.next = new Node(6);
        head2.next.next = new Node(4);        
        Console.Write("Second List : ");
        list.printList(head2);

        Console.Write("Resultant List : ");
        // add the two lists and see the result
        list.addTwoLists(head1, head2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NB: It's not an answer!

There's something wrong on your code; you should add another dimension, otherwise when you have carryover after adding last digit, it will give wrong result;

> 9 8
>
> 2 2

Result: 20

For, over coming this wrongness, you have to add the last carryOver at the list;

```
if((sum/10) !== 0){
      resultPointer.next = new ListNode(sum / 10);
      resultPointer = resultPointer.next;
}
```

this will add the last carryOver in the list;

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help someone in c#

```js
class Node {
    public int data_ { get; set; }

    public Node next;

    public Node(int data)
    {
        data_ = data; 
    }
}

class LinkedList
{

    public Node AddLinkedListData(Node n1, Node n2)
    {

        Node temp = new Node(0);
        Node Finalresult = temp;
        int carryover = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while (n1 != null || n2 != null || carryover != 0 )
        {
            sum = carryover;

            if(n1 != null)
            {
                sum += n1.data_;
                n1 = n1.next;
            }

            if(n2 != null)
            {
                sum += n2.data_;
                n2 = n2.next; 
            }

            carryover = sum / 10;

            Finalresult.next = new Node(sum % 10);
           Finalresult = Finalresult.next; 

        }
        return temp.next;
    }


    public Node reverseLinkedList(Node temp)
    {
        Node prev = null;
        Node current = temp;
        while(current != null)
        {
            Node next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next; 

        }
        return prev; 

    }
}

**Then on your main, You can debug or display both list **

    class Program{

    static void Main(){
        Node node = new Node(3);
        node.next = new Node(4);
        node.next.next = new Node(2);

        Node node1 = new Node(4);
        node1.next = new Node(6);
        node1.next.next = new Node(5);

       LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

       Node AddedList =  list.AddLinkedListData(node, node1);

        Console.WriteLine("Unreversed List ......");

        Node OriginaList = AddedList;

        while(OriginaList != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(OriginaList.data_);
            OriginaList = OriginaList.next; 
        }


        Node reverseList = list.reverseLinkedList(AddedList);

        Node NodetoDisplay = reverseList;

        Console.WriteLine("Reversed List ......");

        while (NodetoDisplay != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NodetoDisplay.data_);
            NodetoDisplay = NodetoDisplay.next; 
        }

        
    }
}
```